# Tinyos not installed after installing Tinyos

Tags: tinyos

I have followed all the steps of [Installing TinyOS on recent version of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483916/installing-tinyos-on-recent-version-of-ubuntu)
 but when i type `tos-bsl`, it shows

```
root@rsmjv-Studio-1555:/home/rsmjv/tinyos-main# tos-bsl
The program 'tos-bsl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install tinyos-tools
root@rsmjv-Studio-1555:/home/rsmjv/tinyos-main#
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: did you execute the following commands? `sudo apt-get update ` and 
`sudo apt-get install nesc tinyos-tools  ` ?

Comment: @Yaron Yes I did that at step 2

Comment: going it again shows
`E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: what happened after you execute `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: @Yaron  big error!!! `Preparing to unpack .../msp430-binutils-46_2.21.1-LTS20120406-tinyprod_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking msp430-binutils-46 (2.21.1-LTS20120406-tinyprod) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/msp430-binutils-46_2.21.1-LTS20120406-tinyprod_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/msp430/lib/ldscripts/msp430.xbn', which is also in package binutils-msp430 2.22~msp20120406-5` and so on. Finally
`Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/msp430-binutils-46...amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: The situation in isn't clear. please [edit] your question, specify every step you execute, and the resulted output.

Comment: @Yaron when  I execute `sudo apt-get -f install`, I get the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried installing from https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main and it worked. All the commands in [Installing TinyOS on recent version of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483916/installing-tinyos-on-recent-version-of-ubuntu/483956#483956) are working

Try this `git clone https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main.git`

Then type the following commands

```
cd tinyos-main
cd tools
./Bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install`
```

Try the commands

```
tos-bsl
tos-write-image
tos-mote-key`
```